# IOS 7 Xcode Search Bar Controller Implementation

Tags: xcode, ios7, uisearchbar

Sunny Thank you for your reply. I made the following changes and now by clicking on a tablecell or search result, I am pushed to DetailViewController but, for any cell I click on I get the same DetailView. I need the detail view to show different information depending on the cell I click on.

I added this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ShowDetails" sender: self];
    }
}
```

New segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        int row = [myIndexPath row];
        detailviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row],_Attribute[row]];
    }
}
```

update:

The reason I am having difficulty in implementing your code is because my information to be passed to the detailview is in DetailViewController.h but as an array not a string:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *Title;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *Attribute;
```

in the viewdidload I get these from my plist:

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    _Title = [dict objectForKey:@"caseName"];
    _Attribute= [dict objectForKey:@"attribute"];
```

the table view is populated with said data with the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.TitleLabel.text = self.Title[indexPath.row];
        cell.AttributeLabel.text = self.Attribute[indexPath.row];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Then in the DetailViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *AttributeLabel;

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *DetailModal;
```

DetailViewController.m:

```
_TitleLabel.text = _DetailModal[0];
_AttributeLabel.text = _DetailModal[1];
```

My segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        int row = [myIndexPath row];
        detailviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row],_Attribute[row]];
    }
}
```

I thought it would help to put more of my code so you're able to get  clearer picture. In my non expert opinion, I think the reason your code doesn't work for me is because my data is being stored in an array (DetailModal) and not in a string.

Thank you for taking the time to help me with this

Comment: It is better to update your question--instead of rewriting it completely. I have updated my answer to deal with your new question as well as reflect the answer to your original question. I hope this helps you. Keep coding!

Comment: FYI: before you get too deep in iOS 7 search stuff, know that iOS 8 changes a lot. For example, `UISearchController` replaces `UISearchDisplayController` and is much more flexible to boot. See WWDC 2014 session 228: A Look Inside Presentation Controllers

Comment: Then change the type of variable to an array and pass the appropriate vale to the view controller. If you don't know how to do this ask another question. Better yet, do a search here for how to solve that particular problem. Don't mix too many issues into the same question. Did my answer work for you? If so, please mark the answer correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement TableView delegate;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSHOW_DETAILS sender:cell];
    }
    else {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSHOW_DETAILS sender:cell];
    }

}
```

Update:
You have to set the value to be displayed in the detailed view. You might declare a property in the header file for your detailView which you might set in prepareForSegue (or in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath above). For example, in DetailViewController you might do this:

```
@interface DetailViewController: UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *myDetailValue;

@end
```

Then in tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: above, set the correct value before you do the segue:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
// TODO select value from filteredList to set the detailViewController, e.g.:
self.detailedViewController.myDetailValue = valueFromFilteredListForIndexPath;
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSHOW_DETAILS sender:cell];
        }
        else {
// TODO select value from regular list to set the detailViewController, e.g.:
self.detailedViewController.myDetailValue = valueFromRegularListForIndexPath;
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSHOW_DETAILS sender:cell];
        }

    }
```

Similarly, you can do it the prepare for segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath;

        if (self.inSearch) {
           myIndexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
           detailedViewController.myDetailValue = valueFromFilteredListForIndexPath;
        }
        else {
           myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
           detailedViewController.myDetailValue = valueFromRegularListForIndexPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sunny, thank you for responding. Please refer to the question, I have updated it

Comment: I have updated my answer for your new question. Please keep history of your questions when you update them.